# Login form with username and password in tkinter

Tags: python, database, forms, tkinter

I want to display a form with a username and password, and in simple case I tried to print the entered username and password.

In my code, when I pressed the submit button the username and password are not printed from the other function.

Can anyone please help with it. The **'username'** and **'password'** needs to be **printed**.

```
def activation():
    activate = Tk()
    activate.title("Account Login")
    w = 600
    h = 400
    ws = activate.winfo_screenwidth()
    hs = activate.winfo_screenheight()
    x = (ws / 2) - (w / 2)
    y = (hs / 2) - (h / 2)
    activate.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (w, h, x, y))
    global username_entry
    global password_entry
    username_entry = StringVar()
    password_entry = StringVar()

    Label(activate,text='Activation Number').grid(row=1,column=1,sticky='we')
    Entry(activate, width=40, textvariable=username_entry).grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=2)

    Label(activate,text='Password').grid(row=2,column=1,sticky='we')
    Entry(activate, width=40, show='*', textvariable=password_entry).grid(row=2,column=2,columnspan=2)

    remember_me=BooleanVar()
    Checkbutton(activate,text='Remember Me',variable=remember_me).grid(row=3, column=2)

    Button(activate,text='Submit',command=login_verify).grid(row=3,column=3)

def login_verify():
    username=username_entry.get()
    password=password_entry.get()
    print(username)
    print(password)
    print('1')
```

Comment: The username and password are printed as " " i.e. just a new line. Why the value is not printed?

Comment: I assume you use **multiple `Tk()`**, read [Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged)

Comment: @stovfl Thank you. I did not know that (beginner). Again, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *
parent=Tk()
bullet = "\u2022" #specifies bullet character
widgetname = Entry(parent,show=bullet)#shows the character bullet
widgetname.pack()
def getPassword(event=None):
    value=widgetname.get()
    print("You entered",value)
btn=Button(parent,text="Submit",command=getPassword)
btn.pack()
parent.bind("<Return>",getPassword)
parent.mainloop()
```